# Modify event end date with fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Is there a way to add one day to the event's end date before it is rendered on the calendar? I have tried the following code which gives a Maximum call stack size exceeded error in the console:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
            if(event.allDay){
                event.end.add(1, 'days');
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
                console.log(event.end);
            }
}
```

I have also tried the eventAfterRender which results in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to need to call within event handler. Remove `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);`

Also you need to check if `event.end` is not null, as in case of 1 day event it will be null

```
eventRender: function(ev, el, v) {
        if(ev.allDay && ev.end){
            ev.end.add(1, 'days');
            console.log(ev.end);
        }
}
```

Works for me.

Comment: When I do that the end day is still how it was before the change.

Comment: Actually I see what is happening. Data is updated but changes only reflected on next rendering

Comment: So how should I re-render the event if I can't use `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);` ?

Comment: @blazerunner44 The thing is even if you are doing it you are changing actual event , not just it's display in the calendar. What you are trying to achieve in the first place?

Comment: I am getting the events from a JSON feed but the end date is in the format `2016-01-16 00:00:00`. I want the multi-day event to show on the calendar as  taking up 2016-01-16 which means I need to change the end date to `2016-01-17 00:00:00` correct?

Comment: If I were you I would update objects you are getting from JSON feed prior to sending it to fullCalendar.